# SSIS: Script Component How to check for last row in input buffer

Tags: ssis

I am reading data in from a table and putting into a text file.  At the end of the text file i would like to append "" how can i check for the last row?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this. If you are writing to an xml file and need to append the ending node, wrap the buffer input in a while loop.

Use:

```
(CreateNewOutputRow for first Row)
while row.nextrow()
  'Executecode
   CreateNewOutputRows()
end while  
'edit last row  
CreateNewOutputRows()
```

IUf you do use this `row.nextro`w will skip a row so it is important to include the first row in the input buffer beforeyou call `row.nextrow`